# Login route over HTTPS the correct way?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, https, routes

More of a thinking out loud than a question.
I have set my named routes in my route.php file like

```
Route::get('user/login', array('uses' => 'UserController@login','as' => 'user.login'));
Route::post('user/postlogin', array('https','uses' => 'UserController@postlogin','as' => 'user.postlogin'));
```

The first route returns a view with a simple login form. The second route is responsible for checking user credentials and redirects to intended routes.
In terms of security do I have to serve over https user/login route also? As a user I am used to see the switch from http to https when accessing login page and I will be really cautious if it wasn't present. However in my app structure user credentials are sent over https through user/postlogin route. Isn't that correct? Am I missing something? I could add https for user/login also but does it really make a difference? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the form being intercepted and changed on route to the user, so you need to secure it.

These days, CPU power is not a significantly limiting factor for SSL. Just use SSL for the entire site. Set up the HTTP virtual host to do nothing except redirect to the SSL.

You'll increase your security, benefit your users' privacy, and [enhance your SEO](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html).

Comment: So a vulnerability can be on serving the form? Someone could alter the form and capture user input on submit? Probably even changing route redirection? I don't want to serve the whole app over https because most of it has public access.

Comment: Yes. Yes. Yes. Serving the whole app over HTTPS will not stop it being publicly accessible — encryption and user authentication/authorization are two different things (you should only do the latter when you use the former but the reverse is not true).